# PowerShell - Create Text File from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell script to generate .sql files based on some stored procedures in a SQL Server database.

On the advice of [this article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calling-procs-from-powershell-with-parameters), I'm using .NET's `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` class to create my connection and run stored procedures. Per the article, I can store that data in a `System.Data.DataTable` object.

The trouble I'm running into is how to best build the file. I'm new to PowerShell, so I've been getting away with something like this:

```
$SqlFile = "$CurrentDirectory\$CurrentDate`_$Library`_$File`_Table_CREATE.sql$ReviewFlag"

"USE [$TargetDB]`n`nCREATE TABLE [$Library].[$File] (`n" | Out-File $SqlFile

$dt.DataTypeString | Out-File -Append $SqlFile
")`n" | Out-File -Append $SqlFile
```

But the trouble now is that I need to generate the file extension based on another query, which will also be a part of the file, but I can't do that in sequence as per above; I would need to somehow save that output and write it to the file.

Do I want to keep invoking `Out-File`, or would it be better to somehow convert the `DataTable` object to a string or list of strings that I could then concatenate into one large string to be written to the file all at once? This doesn't have to be perfect, but I would like to write something reasonable and maintainable.

Edit: I decided to go route of using an `ArrayList` to store the values from the `DataTable`, and from there it's simple string concatenation:

```
$ColumnStringList = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
foreach($val in $dt.DataTypeString) {$ColumnStringList.Add("`n`t"+$val)}
```

And then

```
$SqlFileString = $($SqlFileHeader+$ColumnStringList+$RRNCol+$SqlFileFooter)
$SqlFileString | Out-File $SqlFile
```

Comment: Not totally following - but are you trying to export the DDL for tables/stored procedures? Or CREATE TABLE based on the results of an executed stored procedure?

Comment: I used stored procedures to transform table metadata into DDL for new tables / procs / indexes. The long and short is that I needed to map one set of column names and data types to another as part of a legacy modernization effort. The stored procedure handled the mapping, and then I did further string processing in PowerShell.